# Linq query for NOT IN on joined table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to write a semi convoluted query :-

The query should select a random selection of rows from a table which do not have a matching entry in a linking table. I.e

```
dishes
----
id
name


food
----
id
name

foodInDishes
----
food_id
dish_id
```

So what I am trying to accomplish is select the top most 10 rows where a user does not have a specific food. So

"Give me 10 dishes that I can make which do not contain carrots"

In C# I have a `List<int>` of foods to avoid. So far I have got too :-

```
List<int> oFoodsToAvoid = new List<int>();
var oDishes= db.dishes.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
```

However I am struggling with the foods to avoid where clause. The problem I am facing is because it's a child table (i.e items.foods.id ). Any suggestions on what the where clause should contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple nested lambda to achieve this. If `oFoodsToAvoid` is large, you could probably sort it before querying and then use `Array.BinarySearch()` in your nested lambda:

```
List<int> oFoodsToAvoid = new List<int>();
var oDishes= db.dishes.Where(d => !d.foods.Any(df => oFoodsToAvoid.Any(arr => arr == df.food_id)))
                       .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only queries the dishes table, I'm needing to query the foods table attached to dishes (ie r.foods.id  not r.id ) this is where I'm currently getting 'hung up'.